# How can I make an array of words from a string in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

Im using Intel 32 masm for my project.

I am trying to make an array of words of size 10 by slicing words out of a given string of length 10.

If the string is "abcdefghij", the array should be [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j].
Im learning assembly language the first time, and I can't get any sense for the solution. Please help me

Comment: You need (1) a better definition of the problem statement, (2) an algorithm, and (3) an assembly implementation. There's no need to do (2) & (3) together: you're better off doing it in C first to make the algorithm, then test it, and when it works, translate to assembly.  Doing these will give you a good sense of the solution.  As you work out (1) & (2) you'll get a better sense of what data structures you want, i.e. how you want to capture those substrings/words.

Comment: I already tried changing my c++ code into assembly, the problem is I cant understand the translated assembly code.

Comment: Well, that's a different question than what you asked here.

Comment: So you're trying to zero-extend each byte of a string to a 2-byte "word"?  i.e. copy from `unsigned char str[10]` to `unsigned short words[10]`?  When you write it in C++, make sure it's as simple as possible for the compiler, not using `std::array` or `std::vector` or anything.  Just use C stuff, and compile with some optimization so it's not a total mess.  Or just translate to asm by hand once you figure out what you want your loop to look like.